# How to turn number into star rating while Ajax success using JavaScript, jQuery in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I am working on a spring boot web application. I have a page where I need to show star rating system. Number of rating is stored in database. Format is: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5...up to 5. I want to convert these numbers into stars. How should I do that after getting ajax response success from MySql DB.

```
    function getreview() {
                var productid = document.getElementById('pid').value;
                var url = "/api/getcustomerreview";
                $.post(url, {
                    productid : productid,
                }, function(data, status) {
                    if (data.status == "OK") {
                        if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                            var div = "", des = "";
                            var list = data.response;
                            var listlength = list.length;
                            if(listlength > 0){
                                for(var i = 0; i < listlength; i++) {
                                    var rating = list[i].reviewrating;
                                    var stars = "";
                                    console.log("Customer review rating: "+rating); // for product id 
     15 there is rating number 5 and 4
                                    div = div + "<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-lg-7\"><div class=\"review-wrapper\"><div class=\"single-review\"><div class=\"review-img\">"
                                    +"<img src=\"public/web/assets/images/1.png\" alt=\"\"/></div><div class=\"review-content\">"
                                    +"<div class=\"review-top-wrap\"><div class=\"review-left\"><div class=\"review-name\">"
                                    +"<h4>"+list[i].customername+"</h4></div><div class=\"rating-product\"><i class=\"ion-android-star\"></i>"
                                    +"</div></div><div class=\"review-left\"><a href=\"#\">Reply</a></div>"
                                    +"</div><div class=\"review-bottom\"><p>"+list[i].reviewmessage+"</p></div></div></div>"
                                    +"<div class=\"single-review child-review\"><div class=\"review-img\">\<img src=\"public/web/assets/images/2.png\" alt=\"\"/>\</div>"
                                    +"<div class=\"review-content\"><div class=\"review-top-wrap\"><div class=\"review-left\"><div class=\"review-name\">"
                                    +"<h4>"+list[i].customername+"</h4></div><div class=\"rating-product\"><i class=\"ion-android-star\"></i>"
                                    +"</div></div><div class=\"review-left\"><a href=\"#\">Reply</a></div>"
                                    +"</div><div class=\"review-bottom\"><p>"+list[i].reviewmessage+"</p></div></div></div>" 
                                    +"</div></div></div>";
                                    document.getElementById('des-details3').innerHTML = div;  
                                } 
                            }
                        } else {
                            var error = data.responseMessage;
                            swal(error, "", "error");
                        }
                    } else {
                        var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
                });
                
            }
```

Below is div tag is to display star according to rating number that has been stored in database.

```
<div class=\"rating-product\"><i class=\"ion-android-star\"></i></div>
```

[image: Screenshot to show console log result]

Comment: you'd display a number of star images as required

Comment: Yes, suppose I have number 5 so there should be five stars icon should be visible.

Comment: yes, that's exactly how you would do it

Comment: But the thing is I am having trouble to figure it out that how it should be done.

Comment: you display the right number of images - where ever you need to (not clear from your code where you want them, that's why nobody is answering)

Comment: You mean, if there is 3 number to rating then need to display only 3 star images. is it?

Comment: sure, or three filled and two empty (that's how a lot of sites show star ratings) - how you display it is part of the design you decide on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use for-loop with *rating* as counter end value then on each iteration append your icon in some variable using `+=` and finally append this inside html which is already generated .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var div = "",
  des = "";
//just for demo
var list = [{
  "customername": "abc",
  "reviewmessage": "Good",
  "reviewrating": 4.5
}, {
  "customername": "xyz",
  "reviewmessage": "Very good",
  "reviewrating": 5
}, {
  "customername": "xyz",
  "reviewmessage": "Very good",
  "reviewrating": 3.5
}] //data.response;
var listlength = list.length;
if (listlength > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < listlength; i++) {
    var rating = parseInt(list[i].reviewrating);
    var stars = "";
    //loop through rating...no
    for (var j = 1; j <= rating; j++) {
      stars += '<i class="fas fa-star" style="color:gold"></i>'; //append new star on each iteration..
    }
    //check if there is `.` in number..means .5 
    if (list[i].reviewrating.toString().indexOf('.') != -1) {
      //half star 
      stars += '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"  style="color:gold"></i>'
    }
    //pass them here
    div = div + "<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-lg-7\"><div class=\"review-wrapper\"><div class=\"single-review\"><div class=\"review-img\">" +
      "<img src=\"public/web/assets/images/1.png\" alt=\"\"/></div><div class=\"review-content\">" +
      "<div class=\"review-top-wrap\"><div class=\"review-left\"><div class=\"review-name\">" +
      "<h4>" + list[i].customername + "</h4></div><div class=\"rating-product\">" + stars +
      "</div></div><div class=\"review-left\"><a href=\"#\">Reply</a></div>" +
      "</div><div class=\"review-bottom\"><p>" + list[i].reviewmessage + "</p></div></div></div>" +
      "<div class=\"single-review child-review\"><div class=\"review-img\">\<img src=\"public/web/assets/images/2.png\" alt=\"\"/>\</div>" +
      "<div class=\"review-content\"><div class=\"review-top-wrap\"><div class=\"review-left\"><div class=\"review-name\">" +
      "<h4>" + list[i].customername + "</h4></div><div class=\"rating-product\">" + stars +
      "</div></div><div class=\"review-left\"><a href=\"#\">Reply</a></div>" +
      "</div><div class=\"review-bottom\"><p>" + list[i].reviewmessage + "</p></div></div></div>" +
      "</div></div></div>";
    document.getElementById('des-details3').innerHTML = div;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-OdEXQYCOldjqUEsuMKsZRj93Ht23QRlhIb8E/X0sbwZhme8eUw6g8q7AdxGJKakcBbv7+/PX0Gc2btf7Ru8cZA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id="des-details3"> </div>
```

Other way you can use [star-rating-svg](https://github.com/nashio/star-rating-svg) plugin to achieve this . So, you just need to initialize them with the value of rating .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var div = "",
  des = "";
//just for demo
var list = [{
  "customername": "abc",
  "reviewmessage": "Good",
  "reviewrating": 4.5
}, {
  "customername": "xyz",
  "reviewmessage": "Very good",
  "reviewrating": 5
}, {
  "customername": "xyz",
  "reviewmessage": "Very good",
  "reviewrating": 3.5
}] //data.response;
var listlength = list.length;
if (listlength > 0) {
  $("#des-details3").empty()
  for (var i = 0; i < listlength; i++) {
    var rating = parseFloat(list[i].reviewrating);
    div = "<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-lg-7\"><div class=\"review-wrapper\"><div class=\"single-review\"><div class=\"review-img\">" +
      "<img src=\"public/web/assets/images/1.png\" alt=\"\"/></div><div class=\"review-content\">" +
      "<div class=\"review-top-wrap\"><div class=\"review-left\"><div class=\"review-name\">" +
      "<h4>" + list[i].customername + "</h4></div><div class=\"rating-product\"></div></div><div class=\"review-left\"><a href=\"#\">Reply</a></div>" +
      "</div><div class=\"review-bottom\"><p>" + list[i].reviewmessage + "</p></div></div></div>" +
      "<div class=\"single-review child-review\"><div class=\"review-img\">\<img src=\"public/web/assets/images/2.png\" alt=\"\"/>\</div>" +
      "<div class=\"review-content\"><div class=\"review-top-wrap\"><div class=\"review-left\"><div class=\"review-name\">" +
      "<h4>" + list[i].customername + "</h4></div><div class=\"rating-product\"></div></div><div class=\"review-left\"><a href=\"#\">Reply</a></div>" +
      "</div><div class=\"review-bottom\"><p>" + list[i].reviewmessage + "</p></div></div></div>" +
      "</div></div></div>";
    $("#des-details3").append(div) //append your div
    //then intialize your rating...
    $("#des-details3 .row:last .rating-product").starRating({
      initialRating: rating,
      strokeColor: '#894A00',
      strokeWidth: 10,
      starSize: 25
    });
  }

}
```

```css
.rating-product {
  pointer-events: none/*use this if you don't want user to change rating*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/star-rating-svg@3.5.0/src/css/star-rating-svg.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/star-rating-svg@3.5.0/src/jquery.star-rating-svg.js"></script>

<div id="des-details3"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array.fill() then convert the array to text:

```
const s5 = ["\u2606", "\u2606","\u2606", "\u2606", "\u2606"];
s5.fill('\u2B50',0,rating);
s5text  = s5.join("");
```